# Rules of punctuation

Tags: punctuation, clauses

In the following sentence, I am not sure about the punctuation, nor am I too sure about the general shape and structure of it. It feels clumsy and poorly constructed sentence. Can anyone offer an improvement? You are welcome to discard my attempt altogether and start from scratch.

Your enemy that is part of you, that dwells inside of you, that is the one so difficult to score a victory against.

Comment: One thing wrong here is that you don't have a predicate. Any of your "that"-clauses could be turned into one, but this is just a noun with a bunch of modifiers.

Comment: You are correct that it's poorly constructed. Are you aware that it isn't a complete sentence?

Comment: @BillyKerr No, I am not aware that it doesn't qualify to be called a complete sentence. I thought it had enough components to it to be regarded a sentence.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for your input. My knowledge of English comes from the direct exposure to it; I try not to get myself entangled in the grammar and its rules. For a purist, I realize, to make such an avowal might be an anathema, but there you are.

Comment: @BillyKerr You are right about me developing a sense of grammar; but this is instinctive and intuitive and subconscious rather than something one might formally learn from a manual. I am very grateful to Stack Exchange and the people who contribute to it; it is a invaluable resource.

Comment: Cool. Yes. I like stack exchange for learning. Sorry just deleting some of my comments now.  I don't think the mods like it if we leave too many.

Answer (score 1):

> Your enemy that is part of you, that dwells inside of you, that is the
> one so difficult to score a victory against.

The problem here is that this is just a very long subject, with no predicate (i.e. there is no main verb and object), and so it isn't a full sentence. Essentially, there is at least one **that** too many.  There are several ways to fix this. Here are a couple.

Easy fix: Remove **that** before **is**

> Your enemy that is part of you, that dwells inside of you, **is** the
> one so difficult to score a victory against.

or more formally:

> . . . **is** the one against which it is so difficult to score a victory.

You could also split it into two sentences. Remove **that** before **dwells**

> Your enemy that is part of you **dwells** inside of you. **[New Sentence]**
> That **is** the one  . . .

I also think it might be possible to fix it by using a colon, but you would need two independent clauses to pull it off. The two are linked, and one expands on the other.

> Your enemy that is part of you **dwells** inside of you: that **is**
> the one . . .

Comment: I have had another attempt at my sentence: Of all your enemies, none is so formidable as the one that dwells inside of you. It is so difficult to score a victory against such an invisible enemy.

Comment: @IftikharShafia Sure, that works!!

Comment: Your split does work. If you also care about having your ideas flow smoothly, you might consider turning the 2nd sentence around:  *Against such an invisible enemy it is so difficult to score a victory*. Since you were already discussing enemies, and invisibility results from their being inside you, these topics will be more familiar to your readers than the idea of scoring victories. The convention of putting familiar information up front and saving the novel stuff for the end is known as the **known-new contract**.  It helps readers navigate your prose because it starts from where they are.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Thank you. You have taught me something new. I agree, one's prose must flow effortlessly. It mustn't have anything contrived or laboured about it.

Comment: @IftikharShafia - another possible improvement which flows better is to use "that dwells within you" instead of "that dwells inside of you".